# redirecting the output of a echo based redirect command to a log_file

Tags: linux, bash, echo

I want to redirect the output of a linux command to a log_file. I am first echoing a command to trigger some logs, I want those logs to be stored in a file?

```
#echo "m" > /proc/sysrq-trigger >>   log_file

using it without log_files gives following output:
#echo "m" > /proc/sysrq-trigger
[11474.069710] sysrq: SysRq : Show Memory
```

However with ">> log_file"
m is stored in log_file.

I am expectig the output of the command "sysrq: SysRq : Show Memory" to be stored log_file

I have tried the pipe method as well but no success.

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)< right now I don't understand it. BTW, `echo m >sudo ....` should create a file named `sudo` in your working directory.

Comment: Use pipe `|` to connect output of echo to input of another command

Comment: `echo "m" > sudo tee -a /proc/sysrq-trigger` is `echo "m" tee -a /proc/sysrq-trigger > sudo` - it writes to a file named `sudo`.

Comment: no, sudo is for super user access on linux as this command needs admin priviledges. This command is working fine without log file redirect.